# How to redirect form if is not unique value? Symfony Validation Constraint

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I stuck in a problem, and i don't know how to solve this.

I know use the Symfony Validation on Forms. I'm using validations correctly in my Entity to check if is unique Email when user try to create an Account.

I'm looking for a way to redirect to recover password page if email exists.
I don't know what to do. I'm reading Symfony's documentation, but with no success until now...

Can someone give a hint?

I just need this:

```
IF NOT
* @UniqueEntity("email")
REDIRECT TO RECOVER PASSWORD PAGE
```

but how to do this?

Thank you for tips!

Comment: is this a part of a dedicated recover/forgot password function?

Comment: @Rooneyl, thanks for reply... I followed the tutorials on oficial documentation to create a login form and an user entity. All works like a charm. Now i did created an logic to recover password... its fine also. I just want when the user try create the account, if email was in database, it redirects the user to recover page... all others things works correctly. I just dont know how to redirect using the validation constraints.

Comment: I believe that you are trying to use constraints for what was not designed. What you are trying to do is a functionality, and should be implemented in a controller. If you insist, then try a way of do it with pure javascript.

Comment: @abdiel how can i know in a controller if constraint fails? To create an custom logic? there is a way?

Comment: Removing that specific constraint, the constraint always must return to the same page with a message, them when the form make the commit and  reach the controller, use doctrine for validate the unique email with a count, if exist redirect to change password, if not, register the user.

Comment: @abdiel ok i`ll try and later will post here results... Thanks

Comment: @RaphaelSchubert if someone tries to create an account and the email is taken, I would not redirect to a password recovery. It might not be there email and is it an exercise in trying to getting credentials. Have a separate 'Forgotten Password' function

Comment: @Rooneyl i`ll use the logic to solve another problem, but explain as password recovery is the easy way to explain what i`m trying to do... i have an another use to the result...